# Web service call inserting to CLOB throws ORA-06502

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql, clob

I'm calling a web service from a PL/SQL package procedure and receiving the following error.
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

The input string is defined as CLOB and the destination column in the table where it is supposed to insert is also a CLOB.

Here's the extract of the code:

```
v_answer CLOB := NULL; --declared
v_id  NUMBER := 0;
v_ans_str :=  REPLACE(v_input_str||v_id);
--calling web service to insert the string into the table
webservice_call(v_ans_str);
```

A smaller string gets inserted without an error but a string with more than 3000 characters ends up with this error.
I'm assuming the problem would be due to || concatenation converting into a varchar. If so is there a way around this?

Comment: Please show an [mcve]  What line is the error on?

Comment: You might want to look at the [DBMS_LOB package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_lob.htm). Best of luck.

Comment: @OldProgrammer the error appears during the webservice call as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Well if you don't show us the code in webservice_call, how are we supposed to figure it out?

Comment: @OldProgrammer The code is too big to show here. To make it short the webservice_call function passes the value v_ans_str which in turn inserts into the table which has basically two columns - ID and answer_string. I hope this helps. I did a test by removing the || operator and it pushes in the data without error. So I just need a workaround to convert the string back to CLOB after the concatenation. Tried using to_clob but it didn't work. I'm not sure how to use dbms_lob